# is any jsp 2.0 implementation forcing an error if tagdir attribute has no trailing slash?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, standards-compliance, taglib

In JSP 2.0 specification it says about "tagdir" attribute of the taglib directive (JSP.1.10.2):

> Indicates this prefix is to be used to
>   identify tag extensions installed in
>   the /WEB-INF/tags/ directory or a
>   subdirectory. An implicit tag library
>   descriptor is used. **A translation
>   error must occur if the value does not
>   start with /WEB-INF/tags/.**

As you see it must have a trailing slash, "/WEB-INF/tags" is not enough. It must produce a compilation error!

We had lots of problems with a trailing slash and Eclipse. Eclipse slowed down on editing such jsp files. So we did remove the trailing slash and eclipse ran fine again.

Most jsp tutorials and books don't use the trailing slash.

In the jsp 2.1 specification there is no longer a need for the trailing slash.

I am wondering if their is any jsp implementation out their throwing a compilation error?
Or is it safe not to use a trailing slash?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about other servlet containers, but with Tomcat I have never used anything other than `/WEB-INF/tags`.